# XUnit Theories not showing up on Visual Studio 2015 Code Lens

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, xunit

The issue that I am having is that the XUnit unit test that I am writing that use [Theory] don't show up on Code Lens. It seems to be a problem specific to the [Theory] attribute, because the tests that use the [Fact] attribute properly show up on Code Lens.

Comment: Yep. That's a limitation of CodeLens as of now. You can run individual theories from the Test Explorer.